# How to use 'group by' while having a sub query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT c.text1, sum(c.num1), sum(c.num2), sum(c.num3),
    (SELECT count(id) FROM table2 WHERE type = 1 AND txt = c.text1 AND spec_id = c.sp_id)
FROM table1 as c
WHERE c.type = 1
GROUP BY c.text1, c.sp_id
```

Is there a workaround to loose the `c.sp_id` from the GroupBy clause somehow? I know that if I remove it MySQL will return an error.

Or is there a way to group the results of this query by `c.text1` only?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Gonna add it in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you need to do two separate aggregations.  This is one version of the query:

```
SELECT c.text1, c.sum1, c.sum2, c.sum3, t2.cnt
FROM (SELECT c.text1, sum(c.num1) as sum1, sum(c.num2) as cum2, sum(c.num3) as sum3
      FROM table1 c
      GROUP BY c.text1
     ) c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT txt, count(*) as cnt
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE t2.type = 1 AND
            EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM table1 c2
                    WHERE t.txt = c2.txt AND c2.type = 1 AND
                          t.spec_id = c2.sp_id
                   )
     ) t2
     ON t2.txt = c.text1
WHERE c.type = 1;
```

Comment: Whoa, this works perfectly! Thanks a lot and sorry for not providing any expected result in the beginning. :)